# Javascript error - firstChild.lastChild getting null value in IE 11

Tags: javascript

we were trying get value using code document.getElementById('tempTable').firstChild.lastChild; but we are getting null value for lastChild.
It is working in IE8, but not in IE11. do have any idea how to fix.

```html
 <div style="visibility: hidden">
 <TABLE id="tempTable" cellSpacing=2 cellPadding=0 width="62%" border=0>
 <TBODY>
 <tr>
<td class=fieldData noWrap width="2%"><input type=checkbox name="name1" value=""></td>
<td class=fieldData noWrap width="21%"><input type=text maxlength="50" size="50" name="name2" value=""></td>
<td class=fieldData noWrap width="14%"><input type=text maxlength="32" size="32" name="name3" value=""></td>
<td class=fieldData noWrap width="14%"><input type=text maxlength="32" size="32" name="name4" value=""></td>
<td class=fieldData noWrap width="43%">
<div align="center">
<select size="1" name="distributedNm">
<option value=''>NULL</option>
 <option value="N">N</option>
<option value="Y">Y</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
 </div>
```

Thanks
Daya

Comment: Can you show the HTML of `tempTable`?

Comment: If it’s a `<table>` element, you have to check whether there’s a `<tbody>` and similar elements automatically included. What does your table look like, what do you expect to be selected and what does the table look like in the inspector? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementById('tempTable').firstChild)` Is it what you expect?

Comment: Thanks, we are migrating our application to latest/IE11 version, the application is legacy, everything written in servlet. Actually in IE 8 it is working but not in IE11. I have pasted html table in previous comment.

Comment: any help on the above issue